# Call of Duty: World at War not launching

Tags: pc, technical-issues, call-of-duty-world-at-war

After my old computer broke down, I've resorted to using a Windows XP computer. I installed Steam and downloaded Call of Duty: World at War through it. When I launch it, it asks me if I want to play single-player or multi-player. I select single-player, but after that, nothing happens. Could someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem extremely stupid, but Just add an jack into your mic port(pink one). I had the same issue and this solved it for me